# sed: search and print only the matched patterns

Tags: linux, bash, sed

From a 2 GB Maven build log file,trying to capture the exceptions and its corresponding module.
Log file's format:

```
[main] [INFO] -------------< org.maven.plugins.junt:parent >-------------
[main] [INFO] Building junt-parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
...........
...........
...........
........... 
Exception units:
 <failed units>
 <failed units>
```

Came up with the below options, but both are printing additional lines, before and after the match.
Not sure, how to traverse up and match the module for which the Exception units have been logged. Lines between those 2 matches are not required, just the Exception units and its failed module.

`sed -n '/Exception units/,/^$/p' maven_build.log` as well as `sed -n '/Building/,/Exception units/!p'`

Edit:
Output expected:

```
Building junt-parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
Exception units:
 <failed units>
 <failed units>
```

Comment: So, you want the `Building` line, but not the dotted lines, then the `Exception units`, which are closed by en empty line (is it really empty or can it have some spaces)? I would expect `sed -n '/Building/p;/Exception units/,/^$/p' to give your desired output. If not, please show the actual output for an actual input.

Comment: that's right.. just a `Building` line and its corresponding `Exception units`, if there are Exceptions . `Exception units` until the next blank line.
Yes they are the blank lines

Comment: And what goes wrong with  `sed -n '/Building/p;/Exception units/,/^$/p'`?

Comment: Its printing the entire lines between Building and Exception

Comment: Not in your example. Either those lines also contain `Building` or `Exception units`. Otherwise I see no reason why they could get printed with the command I gave.

Comment: My apologies really, I was not clear.
there are multiple lines that start with `Building` and have different contents to them. I'm looking for a logic like, match `Exception units` first, and then traverse up the logs and match this pattern `[main] [INFO] Building`.

Comment: In this case, why can't you simple add the `[main] [info]` to your pattern?

Comment: I tried that and its not matching the `Building` pattern but matches the `Execution units`

Comment: Are you aware you need to escape the `[`? `sed -n '\[main] \[info] Building/p;/Exception units/,/^$/p'`

Comment: Yes, I escaped the special characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments I figure out that you acutally have a file like this:

```
[main] [INFO] Building bar 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
... Building ........
[main] [INFO] -------------< org.maven.plugins.junt:parent >-------------
[main] [INFO] Building junt-parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
... Building ........
Exception units:
 <failed units>
 <failed units>

[main] [INFO] Building foo 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
... Building ........
```

And only if there is a line `Exception units:` you want those lines printed until the empty line, but preceeded with the last `[main] [INFO] Building` line, so you know which module the messages belong to. Other `[main] [INFO] Building` without exceptions should not be printed?

In cases like this, you store each `[main] [INFO] Building` line in the hold space with `h`, so you can recall it if needed:

```
sed -ne '/\[main] \[INFO] Building/h;/Exception units:/{x;p;x;}' -e '//,/^$/p'
```

If the `Exception units:` line is found, the spaces are e`x`changed, the stored `Building` line is `p`rinted and spaces e`x`changed back. Finally all lines until the empty line are `p`rinted (the empty pattern `//` matches the last pattern, so we don't need to repeat it). The output is:

```
[main] [INFO] Building junt-parent 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT 
Exception units:
 <failed units>
 <failed units>
```

If this is not what you want, please give the real world example.

Comment: That's perfect.. worked like a charm. 
thank you for the explanation :)